# Edit array in SQL with PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, sql-update

I have a database, which has a column with arrays:

[image: DB Example]

I need an SQL statement that updates the array to add another value to it:

```
UPDATE dbname SET array = ["737","669","newarraynumber"] WHERE id = 1
```

How do I update this array using PHP?

What creates the array:

```
            var items = document.getElementsByClassName('box checked');
            var string = '/beheer/po.php?'
            var length2 = items.length - 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
                string += 'id[]=';
                string += items[i].name;

                if(length2 > 0){
                    string += '&';
                }

                length2--;
            }

            if(string == "/beheer/po.php?"){
                alert('select at least one row')
            } else{
                location.replace(string);
            }
```

Comment: Your column is named `array`? (May I suggest renaming to something more meaningful?) What type is it? String? Json? Have you tried using quotes? `UPDATE dbname SET array = '["737","669","newarraynumber"]' WHERE id = 1`

Comment: @kerbholz no, it's not named array. It is used as example
I edited the post with the code that creates it. It is a string if i am correct. I didn't create the original code.

Comment: It's not an actual array though, it's just a string that *looks* like it. So you'll need to update it like a string. Better normalize the database.

Comment: @Qirel would it still be possible to extract the values in the string and create a new value that _looks_ like it?

Comment: It's probably possible, sure. But I doubt it's a good idea to do it that way, like I said - normalize your database.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your array is probably just a string that looks like an array and will, I suspect, be parsed into one in the code somewhere. SQL systems that I have used actually don't have array functionality.

To add to a string, you will need to take the characters up to the close brace and then add your new value with a new close brace. The easiest way for you to do that in SQL I think is using LEFT and LEN:

```
UPDATE dbname SET array = LEFT(array, LEN(array)-1)+ ', "' + 'newarraynumber' + '"]'
```

This way you find the length (LEN) of the existing string, starting at the LEFT of the string and taking that many minus one characters, excluding  the closing ']', and use that as your basis for the replacement string.

This is definitely not the best way to do this, but working with decisions in legacy code that lead to this being the way your database looks, this will do what you asked.

*This assumes the string "array" is properly formatted and looks like what you posted, no excess whitespace, the closing brace is the last character. I'd personally also have the new array value put in with prepared statements, generally good practice to avoid sql injection issues, which is why I didn't have one single string to insert the value and the characters that go around it